# Ubuntu Docker Image Error: Could not connect to any X display

Tags: docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, docker-image

I am running a Docker Image in Ubuntu 18.04 (using Virtualbox from Windows 10) terminal. When I ran the Docker Image volume-test, I am getting the following error.

```
sreeraj@sreeraj-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker run volume-test 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
sreeraj@sreeraj-VirtualBox:~$
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Easiest would be to run the application directly on your desktop, without Docker.  You need several bits of environment-variable and host-directory configuration, and even then the application will be unable to access user preferences in your home directory.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with the particular image you are using called "volume-test" there are a few on Docker Hub with the same name, so it isn't clear with which image you are actually having an issue. You should probably create an issue on the repository entry where you pulled this image. If you maintain/created the image yourself, you should be able to solve it like this similar issue:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1106526